Traffic splitting based on weight : Nginx Ingress controller AKS
I have a simple use case; I have 4 Microservices lets say service-a, service-b, service-c, service-d.
For the purpose of testing, I want to split traffic based on weight like

40% to service-a
20% to service-b
10% to service-c
30% to service-d

Considering they will be accessed over same path: example.com/
I am planinng to go with NGINX Ingress Controller but I saw a limitation on documentation: https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#canary

Currently a maximum of one canary ingress can be applied per Ingress rule.

There is a GitHub issue too related to the same: https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/5848
I am not able to understand what does this actually mean and will this limitation not allow me implement with 4 services. Does that mean I have to create 4 canary ingress with single ingress rule for all 4 services?  All the example for traffic splitting using ingress controller is of 2 services. should I consider Istio as it does not have this limitation
Can someone please explain me with simple yaml code example about this limitation?

NGINX Ingress Controller's doc notes that only one canary ingress can be defined per ingress rule, meaning traditional weighted load balancing across multiple services (like your case with four microservices) isn't directly supported as "canary" . For your use case, where traffic needs to be split among multiple services based on a specified percentage, this limitation means you cannot achieve this by defining multiple canary services within a single ingress rule. Alternative Approach- Use a Service Mesh like Istio
. Something like this

If you need to implement traffic splitting across multiple microservices in AKS using a load balancer like NGINX Ingress Controller, and are facing limitations with the canary configuration, a better approach could be using Istio, a service mesh that provides advanced traffic management capabilities.
install and setup istio first

Create Deployment and Service for Each Microservice (service-a, service-b, service-c, and service-d) using your docker image ( I'll use nginxdemos/hello image here)
# deployment-service-a.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: service-a
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: service-a
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: service-a
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: service-a
        image: nginxdemos/hello
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: service-a
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 80
  selector:
    app: service-a

repeat for b, c and d same way as above and apply kubectl apply -f <filename>.yaml



next steps involve setting up the Istio Gateway and Virtual Service to handle the traffic distribution according to your specified weights. This will enable you to route incoming traffic to your services service-a, service-b, and service-c at the specified ratios
Create Istio Gateway
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: example-gateway
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 80
      name: http
      protocol: HTTP
    hosts:
    - "*"

Create Istio VirtualService
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: my-virtualservice
  namespace: default  # Ensure this is the correct namespace for your services
spec:
  hosts:
  - "*"  # This can be specific to your domain if needed
  gateways:
  - my-gateway
  http:
  - route:
    - destination:
        host: service-a.default.svc.cluster.local  # Adjust the FQDN as necessary
      weight: 40
    - destination:
        host: service-b.default.svc.cluster.your-cluster.com
      weight: 20
    - destination:
        host: service-c.default.svc.cluster.your-cluster.com
      weight: 10
    - destination:
        host: service-d.default.svc.cluster.your-cluster.com
      weight: 30



Adjust the namespace, host, and port parameters accordingly
kubectl apply -f istio-gateway.yaml
kubectl apply -f istio-virtualservice.yaml

kubectl get svc istio-ingressgateway -n istio-system

You can now verify the VirtualService Configuration if it is matching your split -
kubectl describe virtualservice my-virtualservice -n default



Thank you or the detailed explanation。Just a quick question, since I ma pretty new with Azure. Do Azure Native Load Balancer does not have this feature to split traffic based on weight? I coundn't find any documentation supporting this. The closest Was Traffic manager but it works for traffic outside the AKS like for example per region basis.

Nope, it does not have the feature to split traffic based on weight. You are correct, the closest option is Traffic Manager, which works for traffic outside the AKS like for example per region basis. -   Best practices for network connectivity and security in Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS)

Networking concepts for applications in Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS)


The docs you mention are from the community ingress controller, however
this is possible using NGINX Ingress Controller's VirtualServer CRD. NGINX Ingress Controller's docs are here.
There is a traffic splitting example in the examples folder in the repo, which I have modified slightly to be similar to your example.
apiVersion: k8s.nginx.org/v1
kind: VirtualServer
metadata:
  name: example
spec:
  host: example.com
  upstreams:
  - name: service-a
    service: service-a-svc
    port: 80
  - name: service-b
    service: service-b-svc
    port: 80
  - name: service-c
    service: service-c-svc
    port: 80
  - name: service-d
    service: service-d-svc
    port: 80
  routes:
  - path: /
    splits:
    - weight: 40
      action:
        pass: service-a
    - weight: 20
      action:
        pass: service-b
    - weight: 10
      action:
        pass: service-c
    - weight: 30
      action:
        pass: service-d

In NGINX Ingress Controller the limitation on the number of splits would be 100, as only whole numbers are allowed currently in the CRD, and the weights must add up to 100.

Let mew clarify NGINX Ingress Controller's VirtualServer CRD is not part of community ingress controller? I want to understand how community edition is different from NGINX Ingress Controller?
Is NGINX Ingress Controller's VirtualServer CRD feature free of cost?

https://www.f5.com/company/blog/nginx/guide-to-choosing-ingress-controller-part-4-nginx-ingress-controller-options
After reading the above link This is my take You are referring it to NGINX INGRESS Controller Open Source Based and not NGINX plus which also means traffic splitting shown by you as an example will be free. Is my understanding correct?

Yes thats correct. There are two ingress controller projects which use NGINX, one is by NGINX, one is by the Kubernetes community. The one by NGINX, called NGINX Ingress Controller, supports NGINX OSS and NGINX Plus. The NGINX OSS version of NGINX Ingress Controller is free. Both are open source. You can see them on github here. Lastly yes you can use the VirtualServer CRD with the OSS Version. To get an idea of what additional features NGINX Plus adds you can read this

Understood, thanks. I will upvote it. I have posted another question https://stackoverflow.com/q/78499287/13126651 related to your area of expertise. Possible to check it?

In general, we don't tend to log the differences between the community ingress controller and NGINX Ingress Controller as comparisons get out of date fairly quickly. I disagree with the view that we are more limited, even comparing the OSS version to community. Rather we have focused on a different set of features. We have a document on transitioning here but we are also highly contactable on Github, on the NGINX slack, and in our bi weekly community meeting. If we are missing something you want to see, let us know!

If you want to answer related to that question you can. I will accept it.
